# Optimizing the cookie expiration code

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, cookies

I wrote the following code to expire all the `cookies` in my `request`. But along with expiring them, I need to set the `domain` property for some of the `cookies` explicitly. I was wondering if there is a better way to do the same...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session.Abandon();
  HttpCookie cookie;
  string cookieName;
  int cookieCount = Request.Cookies.Count;

  for (int i = 0; i < cookieCount; i++)
  {
    cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
    cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    if (string.Compare(cookieName, "cookie1") == 0 
      || string.Compare(cookieName, "cookie2") == 0
      || string.Compare(cookieName, "cookie3") == 0
      || string.Compare(cookieName, "cookie4") == 0)
    {
      cookie.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
    }

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
  }

  Response.Redirect("my redirect link");
}
```

I am new to C# so not sure if there is any other better way to set the `domain` value to the selected `list` of `cookies` only. I am from scripting background, basically from `tcl` and there usually I can simply check if the given item is in the list or not like:

```
if ($item in $list){
    // Do something
}
```

which is similar to performing `lsearch`.

Anyways, the reason I don't like the logical operators in `if` is because in future i might have more `cookies` in the `list` to perform the same action and I don't want to keep stuffing the `if` condition checks.

I can probably do the same here as `tcl` like have a `list` of all the cookie names and then in `for` loop check for each `cookie` name in the `list`, but not sure how expensive it is.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833109/remove-and-delete-all-cookies-of-my-asp-net-c-sharp-application Just update the response cookies. You don't update the cookie, you create a new cookie.

Comment: Too many cookies are hard to maintain. ASP.NET has other mechanisms to persist the data between pages. If you could tell us what you are trying to achieve, we could suggest you a better solution.

Comment: I am trying to create a single logout page for my sites that are on same domain. So I was trying to delete all the cookies, basically my session cookies, so that if the user logs out of any site, he/she is logged out of all the other sub sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `new HttpCookie` to create a new cookie. Therefor the domain of the existing Cookie is not copied. You'd be better off updating the existing cookie. For example at: [Remove and delete all cookies of my ASP NET c-sharp application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833109/remove-and-delete-all-cookies-of-my-asp-net-c-sharp-application)

Copied the code below from the url above:

```
foreach (string key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
   HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies(key);
   c.Expires = Now.AddMonths(-1);
   Response.AppendCookie(c);
}
```

You can invalidate a Cookie by setting the expires date to a date in the past.

Comment: I tried doing the same as you suggested, but then if I look at the response cookie, I see the domain value as null.